# Start another API from PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, api, shell, phantomjs

I use PhantomJS to develop a script that will be executed on the server side.

In summary, my script will generate a screenshoot me a page. I use the API side PhantomJS another API that will give me information on the generated image above.

To start PhantomJS my screen I have to type in the console of my server: phantomjs MyScript.js

This script generates me an image to use my second API I have to type in my console: nameofmyapi image.png

Is it possible, in my script PhantomJS to call my second API like this?

```
page.open(function(){

    page.render();

    WRITE IN CONSOLE -> nameofmyapi image.png

}
```

Thanks !

Comment: There's a lot of information missing here. What kind of API? HTTP or native or something else? Is the JS running in the browser? On the server? In a browser inside Phantom?

Comment: The API send me result about screen generated by PhantomJS and the JS run on the server.

Comment: Still, this is not clear. Which JS file do you want to start 'it' from? What is 'it'? How is the JS file running? Sorry, this question sounds interesting but I still can't understand it. Try editing your question and writing out your process and all the relevant information out. It is not a bad thing to give lots of information.

Comment: any news about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too late but there are 2 possibilities for this scenario:

**1. Use a new child_process module (new in 1.9)**

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/child_process-examples.js).

```
var execFile = require("child_process").execFile

execFile("nameofmyapi ", ["image.png"], null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
  console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout))
  console.log("execFileSTDERR:", JSON.stringify(stderr))
})
```

**2. Inject your API in phantomJS**

PhantomJS support script injection into the Phantom outer space. If your code is a pure JS API, you can easily use it without the cost of process execution.
See doc [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/inject-js.html).